# Create several representations of one class in UML2Tools

Tags: eclipse, uml

Good day, colleagues!

I've posted this question to Eclipse community forum of UML2Tools, but that forum is almost dead, so I post my question here:

How can I create several representations of the same class in the main window of UML2Tools?

I need this because if class has many connections with other classes(aggergations, associations, inheritance), diagram becomes very confusing.

So, in this case it's convenient to create "duplicate" of target class and make new connections on the "duplicate" class, assuming that target class has connections from both "original" and "duplicate" representation of the class.

In StarUML I can do such thing by just Copy+Paste. In UML2Tools Copy+Paste creates ANOTHER class with the same attributes. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to show different views of the same class inheritance, association and dependencies with UML2 tools.